# PostgreSQL node-pg encoding situation

Tags: postgresql, api, encoding, utf-8, node-modules

So, I'm working on a little project that envolves a node api and a pg database.

I'm brazilian, so the database will often face data with carachters such as á, í or ã

And so it happens that I made a select through the node-pg client, and got the following response:

```
[
  { value: 2, text: 'cent¡metros' },
  { value: 1, text: 'metros' },
  { value: 5, text: 'pacotÆos' },
  { value: 4, text: 'pacotes' },
  { value: 3, text: 'unidades' }
]
```

Both the database and the Client are set to utf8, here is how my pg Client is set:

```
new Client({
            user: 'myuser',
            host: 'localhost',
            database : 'mydb',
            password : 'topsecretpassword',
            client_encoding: 'utf8',
            port : 5432
        })
```

I tried changing the client encoding, adding a utf8 module, but that wouldn't do it.

Help pls